# Select single row from two table related using mapping table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables: Table1, Table2, Table1Table2Mapping.

Each tabel1 data having multiple data in tabel1, this table1 relation table2 is done through the mapping table the Primary key of the table1 and table2 is put in mapping table.

`Table1`:

```
Table1_ID  Name    ,Other columns  
---------  ----     ------  
1          Name1  
2          Name2  
3          Name3
```

`Table2`:

```
Table2_ID   Title  
---------   -----  
101         Title1  
102         Title2  
103         Title3  
104         Title4  
105         Title5
```

`Table1Table2Mapping`:

```
Table1_ID  Table2_ID
---------  ------------
1          101
1          102
2          103
3          104
3          105
```

I am getting all the related rows from table1 and its relation in table1 through mappping table

I need to select single row for each `Table1` row.

Like this

```
Table1_ID  Name    Title
---------  ------- -----
1          Name1   Title1
2          Name2   Title3
3          Name3   Title4
```

Comment: what query have you come up with so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: How do you deside between Table2_ID 101 and 102, for instance? Why do you have Title1 and not Title2 in you result table?

Comment: SELECT Table1.Table1_ID ,Table1.Name ,Table2.Title FROM [dbo].    [Projects] Inner Join Table1Table2Mapping     Table1Table2Mapping.Table1_ID=Table1.Table1_ID Inner Join Table2 on Table1Table2Mapping.Table2_ID=Table2.Table2_ID                       i am using this

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CROSS APPLY` will do the trick:

```
SELECT
  T1.Table1_ID
  , T1.Name
  , TMP.Title
FROM
  Table1 T1
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1)
      T2.Title
     FROM
      Table2 T2
      INNER JOIN Table1Table2Mapping TTM
        ON T2.Table2_ID = TTM.Table2_ID
     WHERE
      TTM.Table1_ID = T1.Table1_ID
    ORDER BY
      TTM.TAble2_ID ASC -- You can change this order to what you want
  ) TMP
```

You can change the order of the subquery.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b17c8/4)**

[Using CROSS APPLY in TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

**EDIT**
IF it is enough, you can use aggregation too:

```
SELECT
  T1.Table1_ID
  , T1.Name
  , MIN(T2.Title) -- You can use MAX
FROM
  Table1 T1
  INNER JOIN Table1Table2Mapping TTM
    ON  TTM.Table1_ID = T1.Table1_ID
  INNER JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T2.Table2_ID = TTM.Table2_ID
GROUP BY
  T1.Table1_ID
  , T1.Name
```

(This gives the same result for the provided dataset, but in real life, the result of this and the previous solution mostly different!

Comment: Thanx it works for me,thanx alot,and i think also others can learn the CROSS APPLY from your answer.Usefull.

Answer (score 0):

use outer apply in sql server 2005 and later

```
    Select Table1.*, ttt.Title From Table1 Outer Apply
(Select Top 1 Table2.* From Table2 Inner Join Table1Table2Mapping 
    On Table2.Table2_Id = Table1Table2Mapping.Table2_Id 
Where Table1.Table1_Id = Table1Table2Mapping.Table1_Id) ttt
```